# Passing a variable to WIN32 API LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi

Recently I've made an update client for my software. It uses WinHTTP to connect to my company's server, I wanted to add a special string in the user-agent section of WINDOWS API in WinHttpOpen. I need to pass a variable to pwszUserAgent of WinHttpOpen which is LPCWSTR.

Here's part of my code

```
//convert string to wstring
wstring s2ws(const string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}


//This defined string indicates a string variable I got previously
string MyVariable_grabbed_previously = "version:15.3, Date:2016/12/10"
//a flag indicate if version string variable exists
bool Version_variable = TRUE;

//define LPCWSTR for winAPI user-agent section
LPCWSTR UserAgent;

if (Version_variable) {
//version variable exist
        string UA = "my custom UA & version" + MyVariable_grabbed_previously;
        wstring UAWS = s2ws(UA);
        UserAgent = UAWS.c_str();



    }
    else {
//Version variable not exist
        UserAgent = L"my custom UA";

    }


hSession = WinHttpOpen(UserAgent, WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
```

However it seems my program kept using empty string as User-agent, I wonder why my value can not be passed correctly?
I'm new to Windows API.

Comment: in `s2ws` you return local object `wstring r`, which will be destroyed on function exit - so this is `c++` code error, not related to winapi. are your code with `WinHttpOpen(L"my custom UA", ` worked ?

Comment: @RbMm No. That's not it. Returning wstring is fine. A copy is made. Or even skipped with RVO

Comment: my code WinHttpOpen(L"my custom UA" did work.

Comment: `UserAgent = UAWS.c_str();` That UAWS ceases to exist outside of that if-block, fyi. Thus, so goes the validity of the `wchar_t const*` you fetched from it. I can only assume you're using `UserAgent` after that `if-else`, and if so, it's a dangling pointer if filled from the `if` side..

Comment: @LynchChen Off-topic, but consider using `std::vector` instead of `new[]/delete[]`.  You will end up with less code  --  `std::vector<wchar_t> buf(len);  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf.data(), len); return buf.data();`

Comment: After @WhozCraig 's reminding of "That UAWS ceases to exist outside of that if-block", I did came up a answer, which is define wstring UAWS outside the if-block, did solve the problem. However, the answer Remy Lebeau given is the best imo.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, nice thinking, I tried also works as a charm. :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it would be even simpler to just use `std::wstring` by itself without using a separate buffer: `std::wstring buf; buf.resize(len); MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, &buf[0], len); return buf;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an invalid pointer to `WinHttpOpen()`.  You are creating a *temporary* `std::wstring` object, grabbing a pointer to its data, and then passing that pointer *after* the `std::wstring` is destroyed.

Change your `UserAgent` variable to `std::wstring` instead, and then use `c_str()` when you are ready to pass it, eg:

```
wstring s2ws(const string& s)
{
    wstring r;
    int slength = s.length();
    if (slength > 0)
    {
        int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
        r.resize(len);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, &r[0], len);        
    }
    return r;
}
```

```
string MyVariable_grabbed_previously = "version:15.3, Date:2016/12/10"; 
bool Version_variable = true;    
wstring UserAgent;

...

if (Version_variable) {
    UserAgent = s2ws("my custom UA & " + MyVariable_grabbed_previously);
}
else {
    UserAgent = L"my custom UA";
}

/* Alternatively:
UserAgent = L"my custom UA";
if (Version_variable) {
    UserAgent += (L" & " + s2ws(MyVariable_grabbed_previously));
}
*/

hSession = WinHttpOpen(UserAgent.c_str(), WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
```

Comment: This is the best answer, better than other solution I came up with, thank you :)

Comment: The code is using exceptions, but isn't exception safe. The raw pointer `buf` won't get deleted, in case the c'tor for `r` throws an exception. `buf` needs to be either controlled by an object with automatic storage duration (like `std::string`), or it must be assigned to a smart pointer with an appropriate deleter.

Comment: Besides, `wstring r(buf, len);` constructs a string object that contains a trailing zero terminator. While usually not a fatal bug, strings with embedded NUL characters can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable you are right about the exception safety, I have fixed it. But you are wrong about the null terminator. Look at `slength`, I had removed the `+1` to exclude the null terminator. Per the `MultiByteToWideChar()` documentation: "*If [cbMultiByte] is set to a positive integer, the function processes exactly the specified number of bytes. If the provided size does not include a terminating null character, the resulting Unicode string is not null-terminated, and the returned length does not include this character.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Oh, that's true. I completely missed the fact, that you passed in a positive, appropriately sized *cbMultiByte* value, and had only looked at you using the return value of the `MultiByteToWideChar` call. Blinded by habitually passing `-1` for the *cbMultiByte* parameter, I suppose.